# IndexError in Python code

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

My code is supposed to evaluate a solution to a knapsack problem. Wts is a list. I would include the whole code, but it's really long. I'm getting this problem:

```
totalwt += int(wts[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But here is the code:

```
ev = input("Do you want to evaluate a potential solution? [y/n] ")
chosen = []
totalwt = 0
totalval = 0

if ev == 'y':
    print("Please enter a potential solution.")
    n = True
    while n == True:
        sol = int(input("Enter id [1..{0}] of item to be picked, or 0 when done. ".format(items)))
        if int(sol) >= 1 and int(sol) <= items:
            chosen.append(sol)
        else:
            n = False
    for i in chosen:
        totalwt += int(wts[i])
        totalval += int(vals[i])
    if totalwt < int(cap):
        print("Feasible: ","Total Wt = ",totalwt,"Total Val = ",totalval)
    else:
        print("Infeasible: ","Total Wt = ",totalwt,"Total Val = ",totalval)
elif ev == 'n':
    print("Okay. You are done. Thank you!")
```

I don't see the problem. But if more code is needed, I will be happy to supply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I assume that `items` is an integer representing the length of `wts`.

If that is true, you will want to change this code:

```
if int(sol) >= 1 and int(sol) <= items:
    chosen.append(sol)
```

to this:

```
if sol >= 1 and sol <= items:
    chosen.append(sol-1)
```

Note that this is because list indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Thank youuu~! :) That was so simple, I can't believe I missed that. :/